# SBS 2011 Essentials: Grant Remote Web Access to non-dashboard-created user

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows, windows-sbs-2011

I found that using the dashboard to create users is tedious because it adds each single user to ntfs permissions, taking an awful long time for a simple task. I rather created a group in AD and add new users to this group.
Dashboard does not allow to use groups, so I decided not to use dashboard, but create my users manually in the AD Users-and-groups console.

**Now, my users do not show up in dashboard - can cope with that, but the problem is, these users do not see newly created shares in remote web access.** How can I grant them permissions for that? I am sure there must be an AD equivalent to do that!?

Thanks,
Philipp